# Custom Django Storage

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, storage, django-storage

I have a web page where people can upload their own images and I want to store them in a salable storage. I was willing to use Amazon S3, but later I decided to use my own file servers with web servers for serving static content (images)

But I'm not sure how to do this. What is the correct way to do it and what custom Django storage should I use? How will I upload images to these file servers?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  If you've decided to use your own file servers, then what's wrong with the default Django storage options, and why would you need a custom one?

Comment: Can I use default storage option? May be then I will have to mount file server(s) directory(es) to my application server(s) or?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start: [Writing a custom storage system](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-file-storage/).

Comment: I saw this but my problem is the idea what to do, not how to do it

Comment: @ju Well, all you've said is that you want to use your own file servers and web servers serving static content.  All a custom storage system does is to tell Django where the files live and how to store them.  If you're trying to solve a more specific problem, you can always provide more specific details.